# Issues using printf and Serial in Serial Monitor of Platform.io Arduino with STM32

Tags: arduino, stm32, nucleo

Has anyone else had issues with using printf and Serial together?

If I do some printfs then a Serial.println() no subsequent printfs show in the serial monitor.

What I discovered was that if I avoid using Serial for writing to the Serial monitor and exlusively use printf then printf works fine.

I guess that's got to be my approach from now on but was wondering if anyone else noticed this and whether there are warnings anywhere telling us to avoid  mixing the two like this?

Comment: Aside from some contention issues, you may want to avoid using `printf`, it tends to bloat your code significantly.

Comment: A workaround would be to use sprintf instead of printf.

Comment: @RonBeyer I've just changed the entire code base from using <iostream>'s cout << "blah" ... so I know all about code bloat. A simple hello world with printf was 13kb adding iostream and changing printf to cout << made that app 171kb!!! printf seems like a massive saving to me at the moment (app now fits on a Blue Pill). Is there something better than printf?

Comment: I think that if you want the functionality of printf, it may be hard to avoid some bloat. I have been doing some stm23L0 coding recently, and I kind of wanted printf to work. I coded printf myself to use vsnprintf() behind the scenes. The code got big but for now that is what I am doing. I am not really a programmer, so this is how I debug (printf method of debugging, lol).

Comment: @mkeith In terms of avoiding "debugging by adding printf statements everywhere" I recently discovered awesome, proper debugging using SWD via an ST-Link V2. I'm using the excellent PlatformIO IDE and still using the Arduino software libraries - unbelievably more productive! Now I am debugging STM32 code just like I do Java code in my day job :)

Comment: I have an ST-Link, but I struggled to get gdb to connect to my target properly. I will eventually figure it out. Would prefer to use a debugger.

Comment: My best luck I ever had was when I finally purchased a genunie Nuclei-64 board with ST-Link V2.1 - wow! Everything just worked so well. The 2.1 version has support for a Virtual Com port which means you can do all your debugging AND serial monitoring via the one USB connection - and it all just works because it's from ST and those Swiss make good stuff! With Blue Pills I could do the SWD debugging and programming fine but the ST-Link clones seem to be V2.0 and so no virtual port - and getting the USB port to work on blue pills is interesting.....